# Worst Band Name Ever

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, music

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6352/48337).</sup>

---

My friends and I started a band! The problem is, we've had a lot of trouble coming up with the name.

We each suggested a few names, but each one was shot down by someone else for referencing another band. We all think what we've chosen fits, even if it's a reference, because we're going for that genre of music.

What bands were we referencing, and what genre are we looking to emulate?

> Tumbling Boulders
>   Gold Blimp
>   Blind Cheetah
>   The Owl's Call
>   Knives & Violets
>   Adventure
>   Shallow Orange
>   The Ladybugs
>   Lungs (Along a similar vein, the drummer suggested "Courage". I suppose we have two fans of this one in our band!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to emulate

> classic rock music.

---

Tumbling Boulders

> Rolling Stones

Gold Blimp

> Led Zeppelin

Blind Cheetah

> Def Leppard

The Owl's Call

> The Who *(found by kedarguru)*

Knives & Violets

> Guns N' Roses

Adventure

> Journey

Shallow Orange

> Deep Purple

The Ladybugs

> The Beatles

Lungs

> Heart *(found by hagfy)*

Comment: What you've got so far is correct. I was going for a bit more specific of a genre, but what you've listed is the more broad genre so... Still correct, technically. :)

Comment: wbhearl, nve fhccyl

Comment: @Kendra Sorry, I'm not actually that familiar with music! I only know most of these from cultural osmosis (mainly Guitar Hero).

Comment: Genre: pynffvp ebpx

Comment: @Kendra Thing that creates air —Nrebfzvgu

Comment: Ah, then 'Urneg'

Comment: I updated the puzzle to narrow down "Lungs". I didn't expect that one to be so... Applicable to all!

Comment: @kedarguru I wish I would've thought of that! I was trying to come up with a good one for them, but I had nothing!

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing you are trying to copy rock bands or 70's-80's.

Tumbling Boulders

> The Rolling Stones

Comment: I updated the puzzle to narrow down "Lungs". I didn't expect that one to be so... Applicable to all!